# Wix and XPath: How to change version number with util:XmlFile when the path is not unique

Tags: xpath, wix, web-config, windows-installer, element

I’m trying to change the version numbers of the following assembly.

```xml
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
```

The problem is I don’t know how to change the value in the bindingRedirect when I set Newtonsoft.Json as ElementPath. It’s also not possible to set the path to the bindingRedirect, because other assemblies could have the same versionnumber.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The string as in the comment of **@Dialecticus** would work. I tested this string online: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html
But unfortunately it does not work with WiX. What I found in the documentation is that square brackets need to be escaped: https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/xmlconfig.html
My XPath looks like this:

```
//configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly[\[]assemblyIdentity/@name='Newtonsoft.Json'[\]]/bindingRedirect/@newVersion
```

The problem here is the XML namespace in assemblyBinding. I removed it for testing and it worked. Also, I started the path with **//dependentAssembly**, but again I get the error: Failed to find node

Comment: This is more [xpath] question than [wix] question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath defines both the predicate (the filter) and the target. For you the target is `newVersion` attribute of node `bindingRedirect` and the predicate is `name="Newtonsoft.Json"` of node `assemblyIdentity`. Combining the two the target should look something like this:

```
/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly[assemblyIdentity/@name='Newtonsoft.Json']/bindingRedirect/@newVersion
```

Unfortunately `XmlFile` element does not support namespaces. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4264) for it in GitHub, but it's old and inactive. The workaround is described [in a post](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/XmlFile-Failed-to-find-node-td7592271.html) in wix mailing list:

> If you have `<foo><bar xmlns="http://example.com/"><quux/></bar></foo>`, 
>   the XPath expression `/foo/bar/quux` won't match, because it's asking 
>   for namespace-less elements, and both bar and quux are in a namespace.
>
> It seems WiX doesn't support declaring namespace prefixes to be used 
>   in the XPath expression, so you'd have to use the ugly 
>   `/foo/*[local-name() = 'bar']/*[local-name() = 'quux']`. Or, if you 
>   want to make sure it only applies to an element in the right 
>   namespace, `*[local-name() = 'foo' and namespace-uri() = 'http://example.com/']`